# Kotlin - Declaring a variable which is an array list of hash maps where key is string and value is another array list

Tags: arrays, kotlin, hashmap

as the title says, I wish to create a variable which is an array list of hash maps where key is a string and value is another array list of objects of custom class.

In Swift or other languages it will look something like this:

```
[String: [MyClass]]
```

In Kotlin I tried:

```
var testVar = ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<MyClass>>()>
```

I am seeing error like "Expecting a '>', Property getter or setter expected".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a simple typo: your parentheses are inside the third closing angle bracket, and should be outside:

```
var testVar = ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<MyClass>>>()
```

Comment: I had tried this earlier. I was and am still seeing the error "Property getter or setter expected"

Comment: Maybe a problem with `MyClass`, then? When I use `String`, the following compiles just fine: `val test = ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>()`

Comment: Also, regardless of whether or not there is a problem with `MyClass`, the parentheses _must_ be outside the third `>`

Comment: Even with String instead of MyClass I am getting the same error during compile time. MyClass is a data class. However since I am seeing the error with String too, I don't think it's anything with MyClass.

Comment: The error must then be somewhere else in the program (perhaps on the line above, or maybe you have other unbalanced brackets somewhere messing up scope, or maybe you're importing the wrong `ArrayList`, etc). The line in my answer and the line in my comment compile just fine for me in a project with no other errors.

Comment: @tech_human If this answer, which is syntactically valid, doesn't solve your problem then you need to edit your question to provide a [mre].